# regex string contains max one '#'

Tags: javascript, regex

Need regex to match strings by pattern exclude if '#' more then 1 times in string

```
var srg = new RegExp(/([a-z0-9#]+[\s])/g);
```

Strings:

```
fdsffmsd,fmsd 
qwjswkds03sj 
ewew 
rfekwjkr#jfkdlsf 
wiru0ksd#erjk#jkls 
# 
casdw##kfdl
```

Result

fdsffmsd,**fmsd**

**qwjswkds03sj**

**ewew**

**rfekwjkr#jfkdlsf**

wiru0ksd#erjk#jkls

**#**

casdw##kfdl

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tYnU7/6/)

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Excuse me for not good task explanation

I update new fiddle
[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tYnU7/9/)

```
var srg = new RegExp(/((\-)[a-z0-9#]+[\s])/g);
```

What we do:

- search '-' char
- if found - match a-z0-9# while not meet any space
- need add condition, match only if # 0 or 1 times in pattern capture

may be like [a-z0-9#{0,1}]   mean # 0 times or one...

Comment: Do you need to match lines that don't contain double `##` ?

Comment: yes, right, only a-z0-9# but not if # more then 1

Comment: Do you need to match if line is OK or you want to search a page or a file for all `a-z0-9#` as long as they don't contain 2 `#` ?

Comment: Can # appear at the very start?

Comment: I need parse text and bold a-z0-9# sequence, but ignore if $1 capture contains # more then 1 times. 2,3 and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Description

This expression will:

- require the string to start with a `-` character
- allows the `#` to appear at most 1 time in the string
- prevents a space from appearing in the string
- allows one or more of `a-z0-9` characters
- allows the `#` character to appear anywhere in the string, including the beginning and end

`^(?!(?:.*?#){2,})-[a-z0-9#]+$`

[image]

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (at least 2
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      #                        '#'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){2,}                    end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z0-9#]+               any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9',
                           '#' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

## Examples

[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/4lLlO9bDpv)

**Samples**

```
-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890     = good
-abcdefghijklmnopq#rstuvwxyz1234567890    = good
-abcdefghijklmnopq##rstuvwxyz1234567890   = bad
-#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890    = good
-##abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890   = bad
-#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890    = good
-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890#    = good
-#abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890#   = bad
#-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890    = bad
```

Comment: what is the software you used to generate the above image ?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Based on your updates:

You can use this regex to allow max one `#` in a string:

```
var srg = new RegExp('^-[a-z0-9]+#?[a-z0-9]+$');

'-wiru0ksd#erjk#jkls'.match(srg); //=> null

'-fdsffmsd,fmsd'.match(srg); //=> null

'-rfekwjkr#jfkdlsf'.match(srg); //=> ["-rfekwjkr#jfkdlsf"]
```

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is call `'your line'.match(/#/g).length` in you method and if the length is greater than 1 you can exclude those results. after that perform your match if this condition satisfies, by chaining.

Comment: sorry, i will use solution in other regex which contains more other conditions

Answer (score 1):

First attempt:

```
var srg = new RegExp(/[a-z0-9]*#?[a-z0-9]*\s/g);
```

**Explanation:** `#?` specifies that a # character can occur once or not at all. This is sandwiched between two `[a-z0-9]*` expressions, which allow alphanumerics before and after. The final `\s` specifies a single whitespace character must occur afterwards (consistent with your original regex).

**EDIT - Second attempt:**

```
var srg = new RegExp(/([a-z0-9]+#?[a-z0-9]*|[a-z0-9]*#?[a-z0-9]+)\s/g);
```

This looks more complex but all it's doing is taking the regex above and splitting into two possibilities - the first where there must be at least one alphanumeric *before* the # and the second where there must be at least one alphanumeric *after* the #.

Comment: alittle not, each line must be split by space or new line